# Recurring events in FullCalendar dow property

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, recurring-events

I've some events that i load from a database. All events are intializied with dow : ' ', since i don't want the events to recur on a specific day unless told so. My events are defined from external events which data are sent to the database when dragged onto the calendar.

```
if($(this).text() == 'event1') {
   $(this).data('event', {
   title: $.trim($(this).text()),
   stick: true,
   start : '2016-12-01T12:00:00',
   allday : false,
   dow : ''
   ...
```

So if the user wants an event to recur on monday for example, the user presses a checkbox for monday and then click on the event, the eventClick fires and change the dow attribute to dow : [0].

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log("attempting click");
            if ($('#day1').is(':checked')) { // day1 is a checkbox for monday
                event.dow = [0];
                ...
```

This doesn't make the event copy itself on the following mondays when all events are rerendered. 'dow' only seems to work if you set it when you intially define an event or am I wrong? Is there a way to dynamically define .dow for a given event after it has been created and make the calendar copy that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekends: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        header: {
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        events: [{
            id: 999,
          title: 'event1',
          start: '2016-12-05T16:00:00',
          end: '2016-12-05T18:00:00'
        }],
        height: 'auto',
          editable: true,
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        var updatedEvent = {
                id: 999,
                title: 'updated event1',
                start: '16:00:00',
                end: '18:00:00',
                dow: [0]
            };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', updatedEvent, true );
        }
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rjzn6yuj/

Comment: i tried to put this in, it deletes the event and creates a new event for each day that month but if you swap to a new month and swap back, there's like 5 copies of the updated event1 on each monday

Comment: screenshot of duplicates appearing when stick = true in the renderEvent call for updatedEvent --> http://imgur.com/a/js80L

Comment: i tried adding a event without the dow property and i get no problem, i was able to go back and forth between the months without creating dublicates. i need the dow property however to copy the events for the specified day so doesnt rly help me :(

Comment: This won't produce duplicates. Please try: https://jsfiddle.net/5mt9seh8/